# Stylesheets do not display on mobile sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, style, mobile

Since the past day or two, the mobile editions SU/MSU are being shown without the stylesheet.
[image]

This happens on Android stock browser as well as Dolphin HD. Clearing cache has made no difference

Comment: Strangely enough, MSO isn't affected but all other sites look like utter crap to me :(

Comment: Hm, can't reproduce (Android 2.3 stock browser) - it looks like it always has. Btw: In the meantime, you could try [StackAnywhere](http://stackapps.com/questions/2370/stackanywhere-a-stack-exchange-client-for-android) if you don't know it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As balpha mentioned on MSO:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93145/so-sites-do-not-load-all-the-css-files-in-the-android-browser/93168#93168)

> I configured the CDN incorrectly in one spot. I'm not entirely sure how or why this caused this issue – my theory at the moment is that the Android browser and the CDN outsmarted each other with regards to caching – but either way it should be fixed now.

I just cleared my cache and refreshed: problem solved!